# What's the complete map from letter to mobile network type?

Tags: mobile-network, data-connection

I was wondering about what all letters mean. Specifically the "R" that I'm currently on.

I found [this summary by some provider](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Blog/G-H-E-3G-and-LTE-Making-sense-of-cell-network-alphabet-soup/ba-p/10735263), but it doesn't contain the R-symbol that I'm on right now.

These are the symbols I've found thus far:

- G GPRS
- E EDGE
- 3G 3G
- H HSDPA
- H+ HSDPA+
- LTE LTE

Comment: R for Roaming , when you registered to foreign operator network

Comment: @Sneetsher That's not completely true. 'R' is definitely for Roaming but it doesn't necessarily have to be when the device is registered to foreign operator network. In some South Asian Countries moving from one State to another while remaining registered with the same network  provider company in both states could result in that Roaming symbol. The reason is because the SIM is local to one state and the plans and policies differs from state to state there, hence they charge Roaming when moved into other state.

Comment: @Firelord must not even involve charging. Roaming just means you're not in your *home* network. Sometimes carriers have special agreements when neither of them can provide "full coverage" in an area, that their customers can use the resp. other network "as if it were their own". That then makes the "R" show up with no special consequences – and that's also the background while some ROMs provide separate settings for "enable data in roaming", with one of the two labeled "national roaming".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter R means that you are roaming. You are out of your mobile provider home country or you are roaming while using a virtual mobile provider. Some providers that don't has his own network can cause that your phone shows a roaming signal, dependent of your phone firmware.